# Install LabVIEW 2011

Tags: 14.04

I need to install LabVIEW 2011 in Ubuntu 14.04. How can I do that? Is there a specific version for Linux? I have searched and I haven't find one so I tend to believe that there isn't. If there is not a Linux Edition can I use it with Wine? Will it work?

Answer (score 1):

At my institution, we routinely get linux versions of labview in the dvd set, and I've been using them since LV6. I don't remember to have put specifically LV2011 on 14.04, but I have for so many other combinations, e.g. 2012, 2013 and 2014 on 13.10 and 14.04. Quite likely I had LV2011 on ubuntu 11 or 12.
LV for linux is limited in HW and toolbox support compared to the Win$ release, for instance has no vision, no fpga, etc, but is definitely workable . Moreover Ubuntu has never been a supported distribution so certain things won't work (I haven't been able to install VISA, for one) but all together installation has become more straightforward with the years.